# How to get the dimensions of a rectangle in tkinter - Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was experimenting with tkinter, and have come across a situation in which I need to find the dimensions (height and width) of a rectangle that I have drawn on a canvas. However, when I get the dimensions of it normally, with the

button_rectangle.winfo_width()

I get an error saying 'int' object has no attribute 'winfo_height'.
I don't now what I am doing wrong, as it gives the same error when I try to do 'update' or 'update_idletasks'.
The size of the rectangle is going to be dynamically changed throughout the program, so I can't manually calculate the dimensions.
I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated.
Here is where I am first defining the rectangle:

```
button_rectangle = bg_canvas.create_rectangle(0,264,9999,300,outline="white",fill="white")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas items are not windows so it would not be appropriate to use `winfo_*` commands on them. Instead the canvas item properties are accessed using canvas widget commands. Here the one you want is `bbox`

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
>>> canvas.pack()
>>> rect = canvas.create_rectangle((10,10,100,100), fill="red")
>>> canvas.bbox(rect)
(9, 9, 101, 101)
```

For other attributes, `itemconfigure` is quite useful. See [some help on Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm).